# Add links to WPF Treeview programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, treeview

I've a simple TreeView in my WPF application. The content is build up programmatically adding several TreeViewItems (and sub items).
Now I want to integrate links in each TreeViewItem like 
"Text of Item 1 (http://google.de)"
The links should be clickable.
How can I achieve this in the code and how can I assign a handler to perform the "Hyperlink Action" ( e.g. Process.Start(linkStr) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="SOTree.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <TreeView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="30">
        My Treeview Title
        <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
            <TextBlock IsEnabled="True">Wikipedia
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.wikipedia.org" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                        Wikipedia
                    </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace SOTree
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This works well for design time ... but how can I add/change such a TreeViewItem via code?

Comment: Ah ... I get it:  

TextBlock tempTextBlock = new TextBlock();
Hyperlink tempHL = new Hyperlink(new Run("WikipediaLink")) { NavigateUri = new Uri("http://www.wikipedia.org") };
tempHL.RequestNavigate += new RequestNavigateEventHandler(Hyperlink_RequestNavigate);
tempTextBlock.Inlines.Add("This is a link to ");
tempTextBlock.Inlines.Add(tempHL);
treeViewResult.Items.Add(tempTextBlock);

Answer (score 1):

XAML for Tree view

```
 <TreeView Name="trvMenu" Margin="367,29,0.2,154.6">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:MenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <TextBlock>          
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Title}"
                        RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                    <InlineUIContainer>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </InlineUIContainer>
                </Hyperlink></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Code Behind with binding

```
    public class MenuItem
    {
    public MenuItem()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    }

    private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


              MenuItem root = new MenuItem() { Title = "Menu" };
        MenuItem childItem1 = new MenuItem() { Title = "http://www.google.com" };
        childItem1.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "http://www.google.com" });
        childItem1.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "http://www.google.com" });
        root.Items.Add(childItem1);
        root.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = "http://www.google.com" });
        trvMenu.Items.Add(root);

        }
    }
```